# Using Html.DropDownListFor and selecting a value inside the SelectList will not work together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application and i wrote the following inside my Get Edit action method to buld a dropdownlist:-

```
  var t=await unitofwork.SkillRepository.getallSkillCategories().ToListAsync();
  ViewBag.SkillCategoryID = new SelectList(t, "SkillCategoryID", "Name",skill.SkillCategoryID);
```

and inside the view i wrote the following:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SkillCategoryID,(SelectList) ViewBag.SkillCategoryID,"--please select--", null)
```

but the above did not work together , as the current SkillCategoryID will not be selected , and i will always get "--please select--". to get this fixed i have to do one of the following:-

1)to modify my action method as follow (remove the skill.SkillCategoryID):-

```
ViewBag.SkillCategoryID = new SelectList(t, "SkillCategoryID", "Name");
```

2)or to modify my view to pass null instead of mentioning the ViewBag:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SkillCategoryID,null,"--please select--", null)
```

so  why my first approach did not work ??

Comment: model.SkillCategoryID should hold the selected value. Inside the helper the property from the model has high precedence to set the value. You could consider to chage to the DropDownList only.

Comment: You cannot use the same name for the property your bind to and the `SelectList`. Change the `ViewBag` property to say `SkillCategoryList`, then use `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SkillCategoryID, (SelectList)ViewBag.SkillCategoryList,"--please select--", null)`. If the value of `SkillCategoryID` matches one of the options, it will be selected. And it just needs to be `ViewBag.SkillCategoryList = new SelectList(t, "SkillCategoryID", "Name");` - setting the `Selected` property is ignored when binding to a model property

Comment: @Stephen ok but i can use the same name for the viewbag and for the property i am binding, but i need to pass null inside the dropdownlistfor as follow @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SkillCategoryID,null,"--please select--", null) . this will force the view to search for a select-list named SkillCategoryID ,i test this and it worked but not sure if i should follow this approach...

Comment: I would say no. You're essentially exploiting a loophole, where the helper behaves slightly differently because it's looking for the select list in `ViewData` instead of being fed one directly. There's no rational reason why the control *should* behave differently in this scenario, and is therefore most likely just a quirk and could always be changed at some point in the future.

Comment: @ChrisPratt so you mean it is always better to explicitly specify the SelectList inside the DropDownListFor ?

Comment: I was a Python developer before coming to C#. Python has a set of coding guidelines called PEP, one of which, PEP 20, consists of one of the best and most simplistically stated guides to writing good code. I encourage you to take a look, and I wish all developers for every language would adopt these (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). The line relevant to the discussion here is "Explicit is better than implicit". Yes, it's always better to be explicit about your intentions rather than relying on some implicit action to occur.

Comment: Agree with `@ChrisPratt. And the reason it works is because if the second parameter is `null`, the helper falls back to searching the `VIewDataDictionary` for a `SelectList` with the same name. And does it really make sense to have a collection of items named `SkillCategoryID` which suggests its an `int`. And once you start using view models, you will include the the `SelectList` (or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) property in your view model and stop using `ViewBag`